# Using keyboard shortcut to send file path in terminal, need path separators for git-bash on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

I have created a keybinding in vscode using this code in **keybinding.json** file-

```
{
    "key": "f10",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "${file}",
    },
    "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

it sends the path of the focused file opened using **backslash**, like this,

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\hello.cpp
```

it works in cmd. but my git bash needs path using **slash**.
Is there any way to send path with slash like

```
C:/Users/User/Desktop/hello.cpp
```

Comment: is it documented that you can use fields in the key binding strings?

Comment: I didn't read full documentation, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go upvote this issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111457 (Git Bash Terminal Slash issue)

It doesn't look there is a way to do this without grabbing the result in a script and manipulating the string yourself.